# unable to define indexed array element

Tags: php

I have this array `$parentIdArr`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
```

And a constant `$depth` with value `0`.

But when I try this:

```
$parentIdArr[$depth] = 5;
```

I get

```
[ErrorException]     
  Undefined offset: 1
```

And when I try:

```
$parentIdArr[0] = 5;
```

it works.

What's wrong with the `$depth` variable?

Comment: Did you actually verify that `$depth === 0` in your code, or did you just assume it does? According to your error it's definitely *not* `0`. Try `var_dump($depth)` and from there you can try to figure out why it's not what you expected it to be.

Comment: `$depth` in your case clearly set to `1`. Here is perfectly working [example](https://3v4l.org/gA7jq)

Comment: I already found the problem of the code. depth was set to another value. Thanks